# How to display database timestamp in django, sqlite and python

Tags: python, django, time, sqlite, string-formatting

I'm running Django with SQLite, and creating a log.  I save the results of timezone.now() in the database in Django, and when I retrieve it for a report outside of Django, it looks like this example:
2018-03-02 17:44:17.868267

All very well, but

1) this does not say the timezone, and I don't think it's UTC.  I was there for the events, and think it's in America/Los Angeles time.

2) I want to pretty-print the timestamp, and I'm getting lost in all the documentation that's about naive and aware and pytz and what seems like a bunch of things even further from my needs.

So: presuming all the action remains in the same time zone, what functions are usable for formatting this time.  For instance with day of the week, Month names, AM/PM and so on.

How would I change the times to print in, for instance, America/New York time?

Comment: Have you looked at [the `date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date)?

Comment: I have not looked at any filters, because that's a Django template thing, and this is running outside of Django.  I expect to analyze and prepare reports from the output, and find console programs the most natural for that.

Comment: It isn't clear to me from your question that you're talking about code running in the console. Even so, you can [use the full power of Django in CLI tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/). If you prefer not to use Django templates there's always [regular `datetime` formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: I thought "report outside of Django" covered that.  And it's not clear how I can use Django, which is focused on web pages, for reports requested from a terminal to display on a terminal or to a flat file.  Maybe it's simple, but I don't know it.  Enlighten me, if you like.

Comment: Thanks, however, for the nudge to look at datetime.  It's been a while since I used it in any serious way, and I had not realized it had grown microsecond awareness.  I'll experiment and see how to make it read the raw times I'm getting from the database.

Comment: My bad @chris, I didn't notice at first that your remark about CLI was a link to a part of the tutorial I had not gotten to.  Very good.  I'll explore that.